# Does Firebase Test Lab supports iOS XCUITests attachments?

Tags: ios, xcuitest, firebase-test-lab

I'm currently able to run my **iOS** App UI tests in **Firebase Test Lab**. These tests generate some screenshots that I'm adding to my tests results through [XCAttachments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/activities_and_attachments/adding_attachments_to_tests_and_activities). I need these screenshots later to be used by an internal automation tool but I can't seem to find them anywhere in the tests results.
I've already set my scheme to not delete attachments if the tests succeeds.

Was someone able to grab screenshots from **iOS UI Tests** in Firebase Test Lab?

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/ios/run

says you can send test results to `[--results-dir=RESULTS_DIR]`
You might want to run your tests and see if that path contains your `resultBundle`